# implementing block storage for a database

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, block, database

For a database class, we are implementing our own database, and I am having trouble how to implement [block storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28data_storage%29) in C++ (where each block is 1024 bytes).

We are to store each database table as a randomly accessible collection of blocks on the hard disk, where the first block is a file header, dedicated to meta data (block 0), and each subsequent block is dedicated to storing the rows of the table.  The blocks are to be written to the hard disk as files.  We are also to have one block as an "in-memory" buffer; we can read and edit the data in the buffer, and when we are ready, we write the in-memory buffer back to disk.

I think I am OK conceptualizing the in-memory buffer, but I am having trouble how to write the blocks of memory to files.  I have two ideas, each with their own difficulties:

### Idea 1

Create a class MemoryBlock that is exactly 1024 bytes.  Each MemoryBlock can store arbitrary data (file header or rows of the table).  Store each table as a single file by writing the array of MemoryBlocks to the file.

**Difficulty:**
Can I update a single block in the middle of the file?  It is my understanding that files must be overwritten or appended to.  If I have a file of 3 MemoryBlocks (blocks 0-2), and I want to update a row that is in block 1, can I just pull the block 1 into my buffer, edit it, and write it back to the middle of the file, *or* would I have to pull the entire file into memory, edit what I want to, and then overwrite the original file?

### Idea 2

Store each block as a separate file on disk.  This would allow me to randomly access any block and write it back to disk without having to worry about the rest of the table

**Difficulty:** I'm not sure if this is really enforcing the 1024 byte block size.  Is there any way to require that each file does not exceed 1024 bytes?

---

I am not married to either idea, but I am appreciative of any input that helps me better understand block storage in database management systems.

---

**Edit:** As @zaufi points out, 1024 byte block sizes are very atypical.  I meant to type 4096 byte blocks when writing this.

Comment: Use fseek() to write in the middle of a file.

Comment: ah ha, I think that's exactly what I was looking for, @brianbeuning

Answer (score 1):

ohh man, you definitely need to read smth about databases internals...

here is my 5 cents: both ideas are bad! Why you decided to use 1024 bytes blocks??? Physical sector size for modern HDD is 4096 bytes! Disk controllers have cache 4M-6M-8M-16M-... So writing 1K is just a wasting resources...

and btw, updating smth in the middle of the file is always bad idea... but if performance is not your concern, you can definitely do...

before reinvent the wheel try to research typical approaches used in various DMBS...
one more good (simple) source to read: google about *leveldb* and firends... -- this will definitely give you ideas!

Comment: Actually, the 1024 byte block was a typo.  I had 4096 right in front of me, but it was getting a little late when I was writing the question.

Comment: Also, the assignment **is** to reinvent the wheel.  Throughout the semester, we are building parts of the dbms and incrementing our design to be more efficient with each iteration.  We are specifically supposed to store tables as blocks of memory on the hard disk and access blocks with a 1-block memory buffer.